# Broken GDM in 13.10

Tags: gnome, 13.10, gdm

I recently switched my 13.10 installation from Unity to Gnome Shell. I did that by installing `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`. Everything is working fine and I'm using LightDM, but I want to switch to GDM to get the full Gnome Experience.

I ran `dpkg-reconfigure gdm`, choose GDM and rebooted. Ubuntu seemed to boot as usual, but at the end of the boot process all I could see is a black screen. I switched to the terminal and ran `service gdm stop` and them `service lightdm start` to make sure LightDM still works, and it does.

Then I stopped LightDM and ran `sudo gdm --fatal-warnings`. This time I could see the cursor and move it, but gdm did not start. I'll I could find the the syslog was:

> Nov  7 22:42:41 tarsonis gnome-session[3055]: dconf-CRITICAL: unable to op      en file '/etc/dconf/db/gdm': Failed to open file '/etc/dconf/db/gdm': open      () failed: No such file or directory; expect degraded performance
>
> Nov  7 22:42:41 tarsonis gdm-simple-slave[2977]: Failed to give slave prog      rams access to the display. Trying to proceed.
>
> Nov  7 22:42:16 tarsonis gdm-simple-slave[2209]: GLib-GObject: g_object_un      ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDM Seems to be incompatible with Infinality. Running `apt-get purge fontconfig-infinality` and rebooting solved the problem.